# Building Pages in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm new in django. I wonder, how should i build many views in django?
Actually i have code like that:

views.py:

```
# BACKEND

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest

# Create your views here.

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

postData: dict = {}

# INDEX - MAIN PAGE
def indexPage(request):

    print(postData)
    return render(request, "index.html")

# REGISTER PAGE
def registerPage(request):
    postData = request.POST
```

But i think that the code can be wrapped by class, like below

```
class ServiceMap(object):

    # INDEX - MAIN PAGE
    def indexPage(self):
        return render("index.html")

    def registerPage(self):
        return render("registerPage.html")

    def loginPage(self):
        return render("loginPage.html")
    # ETC


class RequestHandler(object):
    postData = {}

    def captureRequest(self,request):
        postData = request.POST

    def getPostData(self):
        if self.__postData is not None:
            return postData
        else:
            postData = None
            return postData
```

I don't sure then is a right approach, because i can't dealing with data become from POST request. I would like know , what is the most elegant way to build views.

Comment: It sounds like you should work through some Django tutorials.

Comment: The official word on class based views vs standard views.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/